# Adding model with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I was watching and trying to add model with Entity Framework (using a SQL Server database). In this step, I couldn't select the third one. I searched this problem but I didn't find a solution. I removed SQL Server and tried again but never changed (my connection is successful).

How can I fix it?

[image: image is here]

Comment: Did you try checking the "Stored Procedures and Functions" box on the top?

Comment: Do you have sufficient privilege on those sql objects?

Comment: I tried but I can't select the box on the top. @EzLo

Comment: I'm not sure. Problem might be this but how can i change my privilege? I searched it too but I couldn't find any solution @edgardobanggajr

Comment: If you can access your sql server, you can check your sql account privilege

Comment: @edgardobanggajr I did and gave all "server roles" authorities but never changed. "user mapping" and "securables" can't change btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have no stored procedures or functions checked in your "Which database objects do you want to include in your model?" box, so it makes sense you don't get this option.

The fact you can't select any (hence no dropdown next to the checkbox) probably means you either have none in your database or not the proper rights. Check your database if the objects are present and if they are, if the user you are connecting with from the application has sufficient privileges on them.
If you are using sql server you should be able to use SQL Server Management Studio for this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21690880/6045154) to a similar question explains in detail how to check the rights.

Comment: I couldn't select "Stored Procedures or Functions" too. How can i change my privilege? I couldn't find any solution

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem was only with the table.(about didn't use primary key.... :( )

Answer (score -1):

if any one has this problem: The problem was only with the table. You have to use primary key in your database table.